# ¿Cómo puedo desactivar temporalmente y luego reactivar todos los adaptadores de red?

Tags: c#

He buscado por internet información sobre esta cuestión pero no he encontrado nada de momento.

En mi proyecto actual en C#, necesito desactivar todos los adaptadores de red (wifis y ethernet, todas las NIC) de modo que, no haya conexión a internet ni a ninguna LAN; Y luego antes de salir reactivar los medios de red.

¿Cómo podría implementar una desconexión general de red ( equivalente a un modo avión), y luego reactivar los medios de conexión cuando lo requiera?

*Nota : Hasta ahora, llego a  disponer de todos los IDs y demás datos de las NIC.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando un poco he encontrado [ésta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170507/1468942) que comenta varias cosas.

Para desactivar todas las NIC:

```
SelectQuery wmiQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionId != NULL");
ManagementObjectSearcher searchProcedure = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
foreach (ManagementObject item in searchProcedure.Get())
{
    if (((string)item["NetConnectionId"]) == "Local Network Connection")
    {
       item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
    }
}
```

Fíjate en que se está comparando con `Local Network Connection` si haces debug con tu programa verás los posibles distintos nombre que hay, aunque si quieres desactivarlo todo... elimina el `if`.

Para utilizar el código recuerda de referenciar la DLL `System.Management` (y luego hacer el `using`).

Para volver a habilitar, lanza la misma consulta pero en lugar de `Disable` pon `Enable` para reactivarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerdo que hace como más de un mes, me llevé buscando sobre como hacer esto. Y llegué a ver esto que me comentas, y ahora cuando lo estuve intentando poner me acordé. Ya probe este código, y la cuestión, es que, me da la impresión de que, el código es correcto, pero quizá el firewall de mi antivirus (ESET Nod Smart Security) y no se si quizá también el Windows 10 (Pro), impidan cambiar el estado de la conexión sin usar sus medios e interfaz para ello ¿Puede ser?.

Entonces, lo programé, (estuve viendo la clase en la página de Microsoft), pero en la parte donde la aplicación debería desconectar los medios, no lo hace, hasta que lo hago yo manualmente, ( Edito y corrijo...) y ahí se sale de la aplicación. Pongo el código, aunque como digo, creo que es posible que el motivo por el que no desconecta vaya por otro lado.

```
  SelectQuery wmiQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionId != NULL");
  ManagementObjectSearcher searchProcedure = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
  foreach (ManagementObject item in searchProcedure.Get())
       {
            if (((bool)item["NetEnabled"]) == true)
               {
                conectedNetsId.Add((string)item["NetConnectionId"]);
                item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
               }
       }

  do
    {
     conectado = AuxClass.AccesoInternet();
     if (conectado == true)
        Application.Exit();
    } while (conectado == true);
```

**Nota : confirmo que el conflicto, que creo que puede ser por el sistema o firewall, se produce, específicamente, al ejecutar las lineas para desconectar los medios.**

---

Estoy viendo que, por medio del comando de consola de windows :

```
ipconfig /release
```

Libera las ips de los adaptadores desconectándolos de internet.

Y luego :

```
ipconfig /renew
```

Restablece las conexiones.

No es C#, pero por medio de un metodo de ejecucion de procesos y comandos puedo
usarlo para lo que quiero, lo voy a probar en el programa, luego os cuento. La pega que tiene es que, creo que las redes LAN no las puede impedir, ya que este comando gestiona sobre conexiones ip, como su nombre indica.

Para las conexiones a internet, funciona, aunque queda con el icono de conexión limitada con el triangulo amarillo, no parece como algo esperable para el usuario.

La verdad, no me quedo conforme con la - conexión limitada -, queda bastante rudimentario. Esperaré a ver si encuentro otra solución que seá más adecuada. Gracias por la ayuda.